# Counting overlapping figures

Tags: combinatorics

How many four-sided figures appear in the diagram below?

[image: figure]

I tired counting all the rectangles I could see, but that didn't work. How do I approach this?

Comment: Just count it!:D

Comment: In what sense did "counting all the rectangles" not work?  Do you feel that you miscounted?  (In which case: try again more carefully.)  Or do you feel that you counted correctly, but seem to be counting the wrong things?  (In which case: reconsider your definition of "side"; e.g. may sides overlap?)

Comment: I was looking for a systematic way to solve the problem. And I miscounted because the answer is 25 (I should have included that in the question). I am having a hard time seeing all the four-sided figures.

Comment: Go through each corner, and count how many rectangles have that corner as a top-left vertex. That's the systematic way of doing it.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for Arthur. How can I choose your answer?

Answer (score 6):

Go step by step.

**First Picture**: 1 rectangle

**Second Picture**: 2 additional rectangles. The small rectangle, which has been added and the big one, which contains the two small rectangles.

**Third picture**: The big rectangle. Then two rectangles, which contains 2 small linked rectangles. And the small rectangle, which has been added

**Fourth picture**: Only one small rectangle.

**Fifth Picture**: The rectangle, which contains the two small rectangle and the small additional rectangle.

You go on like this. Then sum the amount of rectangles.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Each rectangle has two vertical lines and two horizontal lines.

There are five vertical lines in the picture, we can label them 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

**If the leftmost edge is 1:** Then the top and bottom are uniquely determined, and it is easy to see that 3 or 4 must be the right edge. **2 options**.

**If the leftmost edge is 2:** Then the rightmost edge is 3 or 4 (2 choices), and in either case there are 3 horizontal segments that can serve as the top/bottom($\binom{3}{2} =3$ choices). So this gives $2 \cdot 3 = 6$. **6 options**.

**If the leftmost edge is 3:** If the rightmost edge is 5 there is only one rectangle. If the rightmost edge is 4, there are 5 horizontal segments for top and bottom, so $\binom{5}{2} = 10$ choices. Hence **11 options**.

**If the leftmost edge is 4:** Then the rightmost edge is 5, and there are four horizontal segments yielding $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ possible rectanges. **6 options**

The total is 2 + 6 + 11 + 6 = 25.