# How many triangles in picture? Formula or algorithm for this?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

[image]

How many triangles are in this picture?
Is there any formula or computer software to calculate this?

Also: I know programming so I can program something to solve this if someone can point out an algorithm for this.

Comment: Is it "number of $3$-cycles in a graph"?

Comment: Try this method. It´s a step by step strategy. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872506/counting-overlapping-figures/872666#872666